# MATLAB Subplots plotting over whole area

Tags: matlab, subplot

I am trying to do a row of 5 plots using subplots (so five plots next to each other). However, when I run the code, the first plot would just take over the entire figure area. How can I run it so that each plot stays in each area?

Also, if I wanted each year to be in a different row, postage stamp style, with 5 graphs in each row, is that possible using subplot? Right now, I run through each year and save each row of 5 plots as a separate jpg file.

```
years = 1997:2014;
for y = 1:numel(years)
    subplot(1,5,1)

    ax = figure(1);

    set(ax, 'visible', 'off','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %  Make window that shows up full sized, which makes saved figure clearer
    ax = usamap('conus');
    states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    geoshow(ax, states,'FaceColor', 'none')
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

    % Plot data - For each site
    for i = 1:length(uID)
        scatterm(ax, str2double(Lat{i}), str2double(Lon{i}), 40, annual_avg_PM25(i), 'filled'); 
    end

    subplot(1,5,2) 
    ax = figure(1);
    set(ax, 'visible', 'on','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %  Make window that shows up full sized, which makes saved figure clearer
    ax = usamap('conus'); % Etc. Same as above

    % Plot data - For each site
    for i = 1:length(uID)
        scatterm(ax, str2double(Lat_Win{i}), str2double(Lon_Win{i}), 40, PM25_Win(i), 'filled');
    end
    % Title
    title(['PM2.5 24-hr Winter (DJF) Seasonal Average ', num2str(years(y)-1), '-', num2str(years(y))]); % Title changes every loop - Year;

    % Etc. Same format for plotting 2 more graphs
    % Save as jpg
    clf
end
close(gcf)
```

I'm getting this:
[image]

EDIT

I tried the following code, which does plot the subplots in their respective quadrants, but it messes up the size of the last plot due to the colorbar, and the titles are not confined to the quadrants. I can just adjust the size of the titles, but is there a more elegant solution? In addition, white space is not used efficiently.

```
    years = 1997:2014;
    for y = 1:numel(years)

        ax = figure(1);
        set(ax, 'visible', 'on','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %  Make window that shows up full sized, which makes saved figure clearer

        %% Annual average PM2.5 concentration
        load(['PM25_24hr_AnnualAvg_' num2str(years(y)) '.mat'], 'annual_avg_PM25', 'Date', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'uID')

        subplot(1,5,1);
        MapLatLimit = [20 50];
        MapLonLimit = [-135.5 -44];
        usamaps = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, ...
            'BoundingBox', [MapLonLimit' MapLatLimit']);
        ax = axesm('MapProjection', 'eqaconic', 'MapParallels', [],...
            'MapLatLimit', MapLatLimit, 'MapLonLimit', MapLonLimit,...
            'GLineStyle', '-');
        geoshow(usamaps, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', 'FaceColor','none')
        framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

        % Title
        title(['Annual Average ', num2str(years(y))]); % Title changes every loop - Year;

        % Plot data - For each site
        for i = 1:length(uID)
            scatterm(ax, str2double(Lat{i}), str2double(Lon{i}), 40, annual_avg_PM25(i), 'filled'); 
        end

        clear('uID', 'annual_avg_PM25', 'Lat', 'Lon')

        %% Plot all the other ones in the same fashion except for the last plot, which adds a colorbar
                %% Fall Seasonal Average
        load(['PM25_24hr_FallAvg_' num2str(years(y)) '.mat'], 'annual_avg_PM25', 'Date', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'uID')

        subplot(1,5,5);
        MapLatLimit = [20 50];
        MapLonLimit = [-135.5 -44];
        usamaps = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, ...
            'BoundingBox', [MapLonLimit' MapLatLimit']);
        ax = axesm('MapProjection', 'eqaconic', 'MapParallels', [],...
            'MapLatLimit', MapLatLimit, 'MapLonLimit', MapLonLimit,...
            'GLineStyle', '-');
        geoshow(usamaps, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', 'FaceColor','none')
        framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

        % Plot data - For each site
        for i = 1:length(uID)
            scatterm(ax, str2double(str2double(Lat{i})), str2double(str2double(Lon{i})), 40, annual_avg_PM25(i), 'filled'); % Plot a dot at each Lat and Lon
        end

        % Colorbar
        caxis([5 12])
        h = colorbar; %('location', 'OutsideEast');
        ylabel(h,'Concentration (ug/m3)');

        % Title
        title(['Fall (SON) Average ', num2str(years(y))]); % Title changes every loop - Year;

        % Save as jpg
        eval(['print -djpeg map_US_' num2str(years(y)) '_Subplot_AnnualSeasonalAvg_PM25_24hr.jpg']);
        clf
    end
end
```

This is the image I get:
[image]

Comment: I can't run your code to be sure (undefined variable 'uID'), but I'm pretty sure the problem is the order you run those commands. the subplot call probably needs to be after the `ax = figure();` command.

Comment: I tried it right under the ax = figure(); and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Use 'get' and 'set' commands with the handles to adjust size and position of each subplot. Type 'get(hsp(1))' to see what properties you can alter. Quite some work though.. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As trogdor mentions, it is odd to first call subplot. Besides that, using `figure()` in stead of an actual figure number (e.g. `figure(1)`) will make it open a new figure each time.

You can move the `ax = figure();` to outside of your for loop. Then call the subplot needed in the loop. I also don't understand why you would put visible off in the first `set` command.

To finally answer your question: I believe, scatterm(ax,...) uses the axes, not the figure handle. After calling subplot you should be able to `gca` for the current axis handle, or use the subplot handle: `hsp = subplot(..)`

---

```
ax = figure(1);
set(ax, 'visible', 'on','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %  Make window that shows up full sized, which makes saved figure clearer

for lp = 1:10
   subplot(2,5,lp);
   hma(lp)=axesm('MapProjection','robinson',...
    'Frame','off','Grid','on');
   usamap('conus');
   states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    geoshow(hma(lp), states,'FaceColor', 'none')
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
    scatterm(hma(lp), [1 2], [1 2], 40, [1 2], 'filled');
end
```

p.s. you don't want to close the current figure, remove `close(gcf)`.

---

Re. your second question: Use `subplot(2,5,2)` to get a 2 row, 5 column subplot. Numbering is columns first, rows second. i.e. 
`subplot(2,5,1:5)` is your top row, `subplot(2,5,6:10)` your second row.

Comment: I put `ax = figure(1)` outside the loop and only there. I used `hsp = subplot(...)` everywhere I had a `subplot(...)`. But I'm just not getting anything to show up.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your code as it is works, but when I tried what you had above, putting `scatterm(hsp(lp), ...` after the `framem off`, I get this error: `Error using gcm (line 26)
Not a map axes.

Error in scatterm (line 49)
gcm(ax);`

Comment: When I run your code with scatterm(hsp(lp)...) added, it give the error I stated above. So there's something wrong with that part. I've added an edit to my question to reflect what I was trying and put in a link to the .mat files I used so you can test it for yourself.

Comment: Hey, sorry, but I realized that though the axes were plotting (5 in one row) like I wanted it to, the map of the US itself was not showing up. Do you know why? Also, the code seems to have trouble plotting more than one year. It just gets stuck on blank after the first 5 axes show up. I don't know if that has anything to do with having the `figure` and `set(ax...)` on the outside.

Comment: The above edit ends up plotting the US map over the whole image again with a small axes XY plot on the left side.

Comment: I did try a code (Above under EDIT) that does plot the subplots, but it shrinks the last plot due to the colorbar and doesn't contain the titles within the plots. I'm wondering if it'll just be easier to read in the jpg files of each plot (which I already have) and have them put next to each other. Haven't had a chance to look into that yet.

Comment: Alright. Just updated the code again. Adding the axesm does seem necessary, but i don't understand why. Usamap should create map axes? Either way. It works for me now, I believe I pasted axesm wrongly from my m-file to here last time.

Comment: Could you let me know if this works for you? Your suggestion with the .jpg's would be easier. Once the subplot gets too small - I've run in to that as well with colorbars - you need to customize it by moving axes positions (use set and get commands with your handles). Good luck!